# Best way to encrypt data in MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, performance, spring-boot, encryption

I have 2 collections with millions of data and I want to encrypt all the data inside that. I am building the application from scratch using spring boot & I want to make sure that all the fields are encrypted as it contains customer critical data.

I have gone through types of encryption in MongoDB and I think Data-at-Rest Encryption will be the right one for me where encryption will be done at field level. I have got the reference to https://github.com/bolcom/spring-data-mongodb-encrypt from many locations on the internet for encrypting data in MongoDB. I am not sure if that is the right way to encrypt production data and just to bring in notice that my client will be including MongoDB Ops Manager soon.

I need suggestions on what is the right approach to encrypt data in MongoDB and at which layer should we add encryption so that person who is directly reading the data from MongoDB can only see encrypted data.

Comment: Note that "person who is directly reading the data from MongoDB" can also be your application, and if you encrypt data at this level you will no longer be able to query it anymore (things like `db.collection.find({category: 12, title: /ABC/})` don't work if `category` and `title` are encrypted).

Comment: I will decrypt it before reading it or is there any way I can keep encryption in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

One of the better way to encrypt sensitive data in MongoDB is to use Client Side Field level encryption.

You will find a guide on how to set this up in the MongoDB Drivers > Security. This is the current link, however this can change in future: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/security/client-side-field-level-encryption-guide/